# making 2 digit month and day columns in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I'm very new to R, so this might seem straightforward. But I have a data frame with an original date column that has values that look like this: 4-02-91, 5-29-93 (i.e. m-d-y). I am trying to separate this column into 3, where months, days, and years are separate. Then I need to combine them again to this format 19910402, 19930529 - I need it this way in order to compare it to another dataset with similar dates.

Here is what I've been trying to do:

```
# Make DATE an actual date column    
dataframe$DATE <- as.Date(used$DATE, format="%m-%d-%Y")
# This changes the original date column into something that looks like this: 1991-04-02, 1993-05-29

# Separate DATE into multiple columns  
dataframe$year <- year(dataframe$DATE)
dataframe$month <- month(dataframe$DATE)
dataframe$day <- day(dataframe$DATE)

# Combine dates again to get string
dataframe$raster_date<-paste(dataframe$year, dataframe$month, dataframe$day, sep = "")
```

The last step looks great except where the months or days are single digits. It's coming out as 199142 and 1993529 instead of 19910402 and 19930529. How do I insert zeros when the month and day values are 1 digit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we can use `sprintf` instead of `paste` as the `year`, `month`, `day` from `lubridate` extracts those as numeric values and numeric class would drop the `0` padded as prefix.  We add those prefix with 0s in `sprintf`

```
sprintf("%04d%02d%02d", dataframe$year, dataframe$month, dataframe$day)
```